# GUI in C using OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

Is there any simple way to create a GUI using OpenCV library or linking some other library with OpenCV.

Just Like the trackbar in OpenCV, is there any way to create push buttons also?

Comment: are you developing for Linux or Windows? If it is the latter then you could simply use their visual studio to make the GUI and then add OpenCV libraries to the project and write the actual image processing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV is a computer vision framework, not a GUI framework (even though OpenCV contains some very basic GUI functions).

For a real GUI, better use something like GTK or Qt.

Comment: In a quick search I was able to establish that indeed there is no capability within the existing minimal GUI for openCV to add buttons etc.

Comment: I searched on net for Qt . Could not find good resources to learn it. Can you let me know some ? I am a beginner in C++.

Comment: I read this post in 2012 and still have to search for GUI solution for OpenCV. Qt is really good, but after a few days of surfing google, I still can't see that the integration of OpenCV in Qt is common yet

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend fltk. You can get started here: http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/

Once you build your gui you can convert Fl_RGB_Image and IplImage types back and forth.