# Simplest way to extend GUI functionality in OpenCV 1.1 on Windows?

Tags: c, user-interface, opencv, mingw

I have a [large real time computer vision project](http://github.com/samuellab/mindcontrol) in C with a gui that uses OpenCV 1.1's built-in HighGUI library. As [others have pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538269), the OpenCV GUI library is very limited.

I'd like to make a slider bar (trackbar) GUI element like `cvCreateTrackbar` that can have values that go either negative or positive. OpenCV currently limits trackbars to positive integer values only. I don't need anything else fancy, just a sliderbar that can go negative.

What is the easiest way to get a slider bar that goes positive and negative?

I am on Windows XP using `mingw` and OpenCV 1.1. Ideally any solution should require minimum dependencies or libraries, and should play nice with Windows and `mingw`.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper around the progress bar class that *normalizes* your values to the range of the progress bar.  For example, if your range is -5 to 5, inclusive, add 5 to the value before sending to the progress widget.  The "+5" adjusts the range from 0 to 10.

You may want to consider using a different widget as **most** definitions of progress measurements don't go negative. (Is your application actually making negative progress?) Also, most progress widgets allow for a positive increment, different than an absolute value.  As the application runs, it adds an increment to the widget.

"That's just my opinion, I could be wrong." -- Dennis Miller.

Comment: Yeah. Normalizing was my backup plan, but its a bit confusing for users (even techincal ones.) `cvCreateTrackbar` creates a user input trackbar, not a progress bar. See this photo of my software: http://colbert.physics.harvard.edu/images/fullres/mindcontrol_screenshot_full.png

Answer (score 0):

[zGUI][1]https://github.com/zetapark/zGUI

I just uploaded a opencv gui toolkit. Please take a look..
This is solely dependent on opencv.
Event driven..