# OpenCV and creating GUIs

Tags: c++, user-interface, opencv

Can I use `OpenCV` to create GUIs that contain buttons, list boxes, ...etc for example?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a frustrating limitation of OpenCV. highGUI is <i>almost</i> everything you need for a gui, but not quite. See my related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874305/200688

Answer (score 13):

OpenCV has **highgui** built-in for making GUIs.

You can find [online tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=opencv+highgui+tutorial) to get you started.

Note that this is not an extensive GUI library. You can only do basic stuff like opening windows, drawing points, anti-aliased lines, rectangles and text. There is a *slider* widget that can be used as a *on-off* button. If you need more than that, you can either

- build stuff yourself (for instance drawing a rectangle with text to make your own button), or
- use another library like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) which provide plenty of widgets (buttons, menus, lists, dialogs…)

Good luck if you go for the first one!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know about `Highgui` and searched for examples, but couldn't find what I asked about.

Comment: HighGUI is very limited and **should not** be used for constructing GUIs. It's main purpose is to display images/video frames, and if you need anything slightly more complex than that you'll need to find a 3rd party library for that (Qt, wxWidgets, ...).

Answer (score 7):

In the `Learning OpenCV`, the following title is mentioned in page `101`: **No Buttons**.

And, this is some what is mentioned under this title:

*Unfortunately, HighGUI does not provide any explicit support for buttons. It is thus
common practice, among the particularly lazy,* to instead use sliders with only two
positions. Another option that occurs oft en in the OpenCV samples in …/opencv/
samples/c/ is to use keyboard shortcuts instead of buttons (see, e.g., the fl oodfi ll demo in
the OpenCV source-code bundle).*

Answer (score 4):

Along with the `highgui` functions that Simon has pointed out, others have used OpenCV [in conjunction](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11655-OpenCV-integration) with [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com).  It is possible to translate the camera frames into images on a QLabel widget, and update the image on the label periodically.

Answer (score 4):

On windows, you may use cvGetWindowHandle to obtain window handle (HWND). With that handle you may call CreateWindow from WinAPI and put WinAPI controls on that window.

But you will also need to override or hook the WindowProc that was set by OpenCV for that window. Hooking and overriding explained here [Multiple WndProc functions in Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538883/multiple-wndproc-functions-in-win32)