# How to detect click event outside modal window form in c++ Codegear?

Tags: c++, winapi, borland-c++

Im using c++ Codegear 2009, and i have a form that should be displayed with ->ShowModal() method.
When the user clicks outside this form, i need to capture the event.
No idea about how to do it....
Thanks to all

Comment: [SetCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable wouldn't that prevent the user from interacting with any controls on the form?

Comment: @andlabs: You are correct, capturing mouse input prevents that input from reaching another control, so this is not a viable solution.

Comment: what about checking the loss of focus (`OnExit` event ) or in some timer testing if focus is in any of your components if not then a click occurred. What you mean by click outside? (another window,desktop or booth? you can intercept messages by hooking to WindProc of window if you have access and handle to it ...

Comment: thanks! the OnExit event does not trigger, because the windows is modal, so its impossible to loose focus.
The option about intercept messages by hooking to WinProc sounds good... can u explain it to me?

Comment: When you say "outside the form", do you mean "on my program's window (the one that is being blocked by the modal form)" or "outside my program at all" or both?

Comment: @Tirma you can convert the form to normal form , with stay on top and on OnExit event do what you need and set Focus back to it. This way when you click outside you lose focus for a fragment of a second (still will see the focus color change flicker)  but you will detect the click ...  If you want to hook to WindProc you NEED TO USE WINAPI  see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7539034/2521214

Comment: Thanks @Spektre. I think it will works!

Comment: @Tirma I use the first option all the time ... in BDS2006 projects

Comment: You probably shouldn't hook into the Windows API for this. [`WM_ACTIVATE` is your friend.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/05/21/10527168.aspx)