# How to make buttons in OpenCV 3.1 using cv2.createButton?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to add a button to my image processing script to save the high and low HSV values for my binary threshold.

According to the OpenCV 3.0 documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html#createbutton), OpenCV evidently has a function which does that.

I am writing the function like this
`cv2.createButton('Button',f)`
Where `Button` is the name of the button and `f` is the callback function (just an empty function)

However I keep on getting:-

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createButton'

Apparently the same function works fine with C/C++ but it isn't working with python. Most probably because it isn't there for python (maybe) ?

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Maybe it can be because We launch it in windows?, many of people that I saw that use this is in linux or ubuntu Mi ingles es pésimo xD

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation says

> Another important application of trackbar is to use it as a button or switch. OpenCV, by default, doesn’t have button functionality. So you can use trackbar to get such functionality (found at [Trackbar as the Color Palette](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html#code-demo)).

There is a small example how to use it as button.

Comment: @DuncanWhyte indeed, but as I see it, it is the closest thing to OP's question.

Comment: So what is the reason *AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createButton'* does appear? cv2 has indeed a function [createButton](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#ga938dc3ab0a9f115156439bd380816e2c), even if as of today the documentation doesn't show the correct parameter names.

Answer (score 7):

```
cv2.namedWindow("Frame")
cv2.createButton("Back",back,None,cv2.QT_PUSH_BUTTON,1)

def back(*args):
    pass
```

The above code shows how to implement the cv2.createButton() method.

Notes:

- "Back" = text displayed on the button
- back = function called when the button is pressed
- the cv2 window must be created before the button
- if your button is not appearing: click inside the frame, press ctrl+p or command+p (for mac) and the button menu should appear

Comment: It works to create a button in a pop-up named "Python settings" that is launched from an invisible button set (10) on top of the frame.

Comment: BTW I'm using opencv-python v4.4.0

Comment: hmm why do we need ctrl+p>

Answer (score 1):

I think it's unposible

```
    cv2.createButton('test', GeekObject, None , cv2.QT_PUSH_BUTTON, 0)
```

cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.6) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:579: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) The library is compiled without QT support in function 'cv::createButton'

Comment: It is possible. You have to compile OpenCV yourself and make sure to enable QT support

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the reason why the button was getting attached to the control panel of QT window. I think the following extract from CV2 home page would help

The function createButton attaches a button to the control panel. Each button is added to a buttonbar to the right of the last button. A new buttonbar is created if nothing was attached to the control panel before, or if the last element attached to the control panel was a trackbar or if the QT_NEW_BUTTONBAR flag is added to the type

[open cv new qt functions page link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#ggad15c7adb377e778dc907c0e318be193ea58964398bbcbd6f8a83e9767ed485880)